# A basic question on java/TestNG

Tags: java, linux, unit-testing, junit, testng

After writing my first few Java test programs, I want to write corresponding TestNG classes. I am using RHEL 5. I see that a typical directory looks like src/main/java and src/test/java.

(a) Who creates such directory? Do we create it manually? or there is a way to create test directory structure corresponding to main code dir structure.

(b) Also, how do I run these testNG classes from command line? Do I need to have any additional extra jars like testng.jar or something to support these annotations or these annotations are supported in default jdk 1.6?

(c) Also, when I create a TestNG class from Eclipse, it necessarily asks for a package name. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*a) Who creates such directory? Do we create it manually? or there is a way to create test directory structure corresponding to main code dir structure.*

Its created by some tool like Maven or yourself. Tools will just create a test folder, further folders/structure are purely specific to practices in your project.

*(b) Also, how do I run these testNG classes from command line? Do I need to have any additional extra jars like testng.jar or something to support these annotations or these annotations are supported in default jdk 1.6?*

Here is [nice link](http://membres.multimania.fr/testng/#_Toc134939684) which shows how to run TestNG classes from command line including the extra jars needed

*(c) Also, when I create a TestNG class from Eclipse, it necessarily asks for a package name. Why is it so?*

I don't any reason other than enforcing a fair practice.